# This four-by-four Magic Square uses all the integers from -7 to 8. Complete the square. More Magic Squares!

Tags: mathematics, magic-square

This four-by-four Magic Square uses all the integers from -7 to 8. Complete the square.

This is what has been given so far:

-7 _ _ _

_ -2 _ +1

_ _ +3 _

+5 _ _ _

Please Help. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

So, first of all, magic squares are still valid when:

> They are rotated,

and

> All numbers are added to a same number (the number can be negative)

Therefore, given that the normal 1-16 magic square will be:

> 16 2 3 13
>  5 11 10 8
>  9  7 6 12
>  4 14 15 1

After rotation, you get:

> 13  8 12  1 
>  3 10  6 15 
>  2 11  7 14 
>  16  5  9  4

and adding each number by -8, you get:

> +5  0 -4 -7 
>  -5 +2 -2 +7 
>  -8 +3 -1 +6 
>  +8 -3 +1 -4

which is the final answer!

Comment: I was actually about to post a similar solution myself. (+1) :P